# Reading file from localhost

Tags: android

I am trying to read a text file from my localhost (WAMP), but getting nothing back. 
Could someone point out what I am doing wrong please.
This is how I am trying to achieve it.

```
        try {
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/text.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));           
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {                
            tv.append(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {      }
```

It works with a true URL, but not whenever I use localhost. I have tried using *localhost* and *127.0.0.1* in URL too.

Comment: That's not localhost (localhost is the android itself), that's an alias to loopback of the machine hosting the emulator. You are using the emulator, right?  The special 10.0.2.2 alias to the development host's loopback is only available on the emulator, and not on an actual android device.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! Yeah I was testing it on my physical device and never thought of host's loopback being available for emulators only. It works fine with emulator but not with the phone. Tnx once more!

Comment: Easiest way to test on a device is usually to put it on a wifi network and get at the dev machine by it's ip on the wifi.  If USB tethering is available some report that has the side effect of letting the device contact the pc.